# Can a function that calls itself through setTimout lead to overflow?

Tags: javascript, callstack

Given a function like so . . .

```
function self_time() {
  console.log('hi');
  setTimeout(self_time, 1000);
}
```

can this potentially lead to a stack overflow? I know this is not exactly a recursive call and that javascript is async, but could something like this run indefinitely without exhausting the resources?

also what about a try-catch situation like this . . .

```
function try_it() {
  try {
    console.log('im trying something...');
  } catch(e) { 
    //i failed so im going to try again in 1 second
    setTimeout(try_it, 1000);
  }
}
```

say that the function was failing indefinitely, would it run out of resources?

i know setInterval is an alternative, but a call like this when successful would no longer need to check intermittently.

Comment: I am not sure, but you allways can use `var intervalID = setInterval(function, 1000);` and when you're successful you can `clearInterval(intervalID);` I know it's not what you're asked for, but that's allways an option

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: Both of your functions can run indefinitely without exhausting resources.

Comment: Only if you're doing something like setting more than 1 recursive timeout in each iteration from what I can think about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither function will ever run out of resources; no recursion is actually occurring because the browser calls functions passed to `setTimeout` asynchronously. You can, however, make your logic a little bit clearer by rolling your own `attemptEvery` utility, as I have done below:

```js
function attemptEvery (ms, fn) {
  var token = setInterval(function () {
    try {
      fn.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 2))
      clearInterval(token)
    } catch (e) {}
  }, ms)
}

attemptEvery(100, function () {

    dangerousOperation()
    console.log('Success!')
})

function dangerousOperation () {
    console.log('Attempting dangerous operation!')
    if (Math.random() < .6) throw Error()
}
```